# Return Specified Values From Another Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, search-indexing

I have two Excel sheets open. The first sheet has data organized by Student ID and by School (two different column). In the second Excel sheet, I simply want to return a column that shows the Student ID of all students belonging to a specified school. How do I do this dynamically? If I change the specified school, then presumptively my Student ID list too should change. Thanks in advance - I'm a newbie here!

Comment: If you have office 365 Excel, look into FILTER().  If not then you will need to use a version of INDEX() with SMALL().

Comment: Why not just filter it in place?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a PivotTable of your data. Add "School" field to filters area, and "Student ID" to rows area. Don't add any values.
Hey presto, a list of students filtered by school.

Instead of using a filter, consider adding a slicer for the Pivot Table for a more end-user self-service look and feel. No good if list of schools is really long though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Index + Small + IF function, you may refer to following sample.

The following image shows Student ID and and School.

[image]

I enter formula `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$12,SMALL(IF($A$2=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$12,ROW($2:$12)-1,4^8),ROW(A1))),"")` in cell B2, then drop down.

If I change the School in A2 via Drop-down list, the corresponding student IDs will be queried.

[image]